# WPF application process is not unloaded after main form is closed

Tags: .net, wpf

When I close my WPF application main form, the appropriate process is not unloaded. What are the common reasons for that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at value of [ShutdownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) in your App.xaml file,
by default it:

> A ShutdownMode enumeration value. The default value is
>   OnLastWindowClose.

So it could be that some window still not closed/released by the process.

Answer (score 2):

Some common reasons:

Something is still executing in the Application class's code (look for the Main method, or wherever else you're instantiating the main window).

The form has some OnClose code that's still running.

Some thread isn't done executing yet.

You're looking at the debugger task (the one with vshost in the name), not the application task. This happens when you run your code by pressing F5 in Visual Studio.

Profiling?

These might not be your reason, though, so keep on looking! It might be time to load up the debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: I would correct your point about threads. It is valid only for foreground threads (Background property set to false)